# Convert custom string to date in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data in from a csv file and I need to convert 3 columns from strings to dates.

The date string are given in this format, where the day is first, then the month abbreviation and then the year abbreviated:

```
01Aug23
02Dec22
03Jan24
```

I have tried the following, but it leads to a "unconverted data remains" error

```
df['StartDate'] = datetime.strptime(df['StartDate'].iloc[i], '%d%b%y')
```

I am unsure what exactly I am doing wrong. Any suggestions help

I am using python pandas

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime` to handle a Series as input